# Un bracelet en caoutchouc baptisé "Nous prions pour le Japon" - I don't understand what "baptisé" means here

Tags: sens

> Le week-end dernier, elle a annoncé qu'elle a conçu un bracelet en caoutchouc **baptisé** « Nous prions pour le Japon » et qui est en vente sur son site pour le prix de 5 $. Les recettes collectées iront aux efforts de secours.

**Un bracelet en caoutchouc** means *a rubber bracelet* or *a bracelet made of rubber*. No problem with that. What comes next is where I have trouble. How do you understand the word **baptisé**? Generally, it means *baptized* or *christened*, but that doesn't really make sense in this context.

Comment: In this context it means *to name*, or give it a name, in French: nommer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

French has only one word where English has two. *Baptiser* means to admit or initiate someone into the Christian Church by baptism **and** to give them a name in the course of the ceremony of baptism.
 It can also be used in a figurative way as a synonym of *appeler*, *nommer*/*surnommer* and applied not only to people but to objects too. It is exactly the same in English with the verb "to christen", here is part of the definition of  "to christen" in the OED:

> To name, give a name to; often with complement, to call by the name of.  *colloq.*

So just think of *baptiser* as "to christen". The part of the sentence you don't understand could be rephrased thus:

> un bracelet en caoutchouc **qu'elle a appelé**  « Nous prions pour le Japon »